# Elm installed package location

Tags: package, elm

Where does Elm install the packages that I added it to the project?
I'd like to peek the source code but I don't find the files. I was expecting the files to be in the project folder.

Comment: It is not in `./elm-stuff/packages/`?

Comment: I was expecting it but I don't see them there. Only 3 files. ```summary.dat``` ```*.elmi``` ```*.elmo``` files.
I use webpack elm loader to build it but for fetching packages it should not matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `elm-0.19` packages are installed into the global cache in `~/.elm`.

If you try `ls ~/.elm/0.19.0/package` in your terminal you should see a list of package authors.

For example, to look at the Elm core versions you have, `ls ~/.elm/0.19.0/package/elm/core`.

Note that because of how https://package.elm-lang.org works, the source code for all modules is required to be on Github and is linked as a "Browse source" link on each module page, so you can also look at it there before you install anything.

Note: It may also be overridden using the `ELM_HOME` environment variable, which may be worth checking in case it's not where you expect.